# How to Spilt Address in Customer grid CSV Export

Tags: adminhtml, export, magento2.2.3, customer-grid, customer-csv

While exporting customers by going to Customer->All Customers-> Export CSV from grid, billing & shipping addresses are shown as full address. Instead of full address, I need to have separate columns like `billing_address_street,billing_address_city,shipping_address_street,shipping_address_city` etc..,

I understandard these are coming from listing file `module-customer\view\adminhtml\ui_component\customer_listing.xml` and mapped to a table.

Is there a way to split the full billing & shipping address during the export operation instead of adding new columns to the listing or
how to add address columns to `customer_grid_flat` table and populate the data in csv file

Your ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Part one: Understanding Magento

Let me first explain what's going on, and why you're getting the result you're getting:

If you look at the columns defined in `module-customer\view\adminhtml\ui_component\customer_listing.xml` you'll see that stuff like `billing_postcode` and `billing_city` are already available / exported, only they're labeled als `ZIP` and `City`:

```
<column name="billing_postcode" sortOrder="70">
    <settings>
        <filter>text</filter>
        <editor>
            <editorType>text</editorType>
        </editor>
        <label translate="true">ZIP</label>
    </settings>
</column>
<column name="billing_city" sortOrder="210">
    <settings>
        <filter>text</filter>
        <editor>
            <editorType>text</editorType>
        </editor>
        <label translate="true">City</label>
        <visible>false</visible>
    </settings>
</column>
```

The addresses that are exported in as `Billing Address` and `Shipping Address` are `billing_full` and `shipping_full`:

```
<column name="billing_full" sortOrder="150">
    <settings>
        <label translate="true">Billing Address</label>
        <visible>false</visible>
    </settings>
</column>
<column name="shipping_full" sortOrder="160">
    <settings>
        <label translate="true">Shipping Address</label>
        <visible>false</visible>
    </settings>
</column>
```

These values are not as-is stored in the default database, but are generated for convenience purposes (like listing in a grid, or exporting in your case) in the flat table. See `indexer.xml`:

```
<fieldset name="billing" source="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Address\Collection"
          provider="Magento\Customer\Model\Indexer\Address\AttributeProvider">
    <reference fieldset="customer" from="entity_id" to="default_billing"/>
    <field name="full" xsi:type="searchable" dataType="text" handler="BillingAddressHandler"/>
    ...
```

And `BillingAddressHandler` is a virtual type:

```
<virtualType name="BillingAddressHandler" type="Magento\Framework\Indexer\Handler\ConcatHandler">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="concatExpression" xsi:type="object">BillingAddressExpression</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Which has an expression that builds the space concatenated data you have in your column:

```
<virtualType name="BillingAddressExpression" type="Magento\Framework\DB\Sql\ConcatExpression">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="prefix" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="tableAlias" xsi:type="string">billing</item>
                <item name="columnName" xsi:type="string">street</item>
            </item>
            <item name="firstname" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="tableAlias" xsi:type="string">billing</item>
                <item name="columnName" xsi:type="string">city</item>
            </item>
            <item name="middlename" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="tableAlias" xsi:type="string">billing</item>
                <item name="columnName" xsi:type="string">region</item>
            </item>
            <item name="lastname" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="tableAlias" xsi:type="string">billing</item>
                <item name="columnName" xsi:type="string">postcode</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

### Part two: Implementing

Now, as you can see, the export is done from the flat grid (=indexed) table, so if you want to export additional columns, you have to make sure that these are available.

As you can see in `module-customer/etc/indexer.xml`, there are actually already a lot of fields for the billing information, like postcode, city, street, etc. However, for shipping there is only the `full`-field (which maps to `shipping_full`):

```
<fieldset name="shipping" source="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Address\Collection">
    <reference fieldset="customer" from="entity_id" to="default_shipping"/>
    <field name="full" xsi:type="searchable" dataType="text" handler="ShippingAddressHandler"/>
</fieldset>

<fieldset name="billing" source="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Address\Collection"
          provider="Magento\Customer\Model\Indexer\Address\AttributeProvider">
    <reference fieldset="customer" from="entity_id" to="default_billing"/>
    <field name="full" xsi:type="searchable" dataType="text" handler="BillingAddressHandler"/>
    <field name="firstname" xsi:type="searchable" dataType="varchar"/>
    <field name="lastname" xsi:type="searchable" dataType="varchar"/>
    <field name="telephone" xsi:type="searchable" dataType="varchar"/>
    <field name="postcode" xsi:type="searchable" dataType="varchar"/>
    <field name="country_id" xsi:type="filterable" dataType="varchar"/>
    <field name="region" xsi:type="searchable" dataType="varchar"/>
    <field name="street" xsi:type="searchable" dataType="varchar"/>
    <field name="city" xsi:type="searchable" dataType="varchar"/>
    <field name="fax" xsi:type="searchable" dataType="varchar"/>
    <field name="vat_id" xsi:type="searchable" dataType="varchar"/>
    <field name="company" xsi:type="searchable" dataType="varchar"/>
</fieldset>
```

Now if you also want to have more shipping details indexed, just create your own module that hooks with it's own `indexer.xml` into this one (XML files are merged together after all), and add you desired fields:

```
<fieldset name="shipping" source="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Address\Collection">
    <field name="postcode" xsi:type="filterable" dataType="varchar"/>
    <field name="street" xsi:type="filterable" dataType="varchar"/>
    <field name="city" xsi:type="filterable" dataType="varchar"/>
</fieldset>
```

Please note that at this point if you mark too much fields as `xsi:type="searchable"` you might get a SQL error: `Syntax error or access violation: 1070 Too many key parts specified; max 16 parts allowed`. This is because if a field is searchable it gets added to the index, and (depending on the configuration of your database) MySQL might not allow too big indexes.
The `xsi:type="filterable"` is required for `\Magento\Framework\Indexer\SaveHandler\Grid` to populate the tables during indexing.

Flush the cache and run the reindex command to populate the table now:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex customer_grid
```

Now that the indexer is setup and the table is indexed, you can see in the database the extra columns present in `customer_grid_flat` with the proper data.

### Part 3: Presenting

Now the last thing to do is add the columns to our `module-customer/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml`. For example:

```
<column name="shipping_postcode" sortOrder="1000">
    <settings>
        <filter>text</filter>
        <editor>
            <editorType>text</editorType>
        </editor>
        <label translate="true">Shipping ZIP</label>
    </settings>
</column>
<column name="shipping_street" sortOrder="1001">
    <settings>
        <label translate="true">Shipping Street Address</label>
        <visible>false</visible>
    </settings>
</column>
<column name="shipping_city" sortOrder="1002">
    <settings>
        <filter>text</filter>
        <editor>
            <editorType>text</editorType>
        </editor>
        <label translate="true">Shipping City</label>
        <visible>false</visible>
    </settings>
</column>
```

And the result:

[image: screenshot magento]

[image: csv]

So as you can see, it's not a matter of manipulating the existing columns, but rather understanding where the data comes from and to add your own columns to it.

Hopefully this answer helps you.